# Find the owners of all the folders within a given path

Tags: vbscript, scripting

I am trying to find the owners of all the folders in a given path. I have the following code:

```
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
For Each objFolder In objFSO.GetFolder("C:\Windows").SubFolders
    strpath = objFolder.Path
    WScript.Echo strpath
Next
```

My end goal is to put the path and and owner of all the folders from the given path into a text file.

Could someone help me find the owner of a folder and be able to place this owner name into a variable. I could then use this to improve my existing code.

Comment: Check [this page](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/ccbc8b1f-bc27-4aa7-9826-f4461d9b7e83)

Answer (score 0):

As JoSerra mentioned [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46154147/vbscript-to-find-the-owners-of-all-the-folders-within-a-given-path#comment79271098_46154147) you can retrieve the owner of a file or folder via the WMI class [`Win32_LogicalFileSecuritySetting`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394180.aspx). The [sample code](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/ccbc8b1f-bc27-4aa7-9826-f4461d9b7e83) from the Script Center is mostly accurate. I would, however, recommend using double quotes instead of single quotes around the path.

Single quotes (unlike double quotes) are [valid characters in a path](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365247.aspx#naming_conventions). If you invoke the statement `wmi.Get("Win32_LogicalFileSecuritySetting.Path='" & path & "'")` with a path containing a single quote, the call will fail with an "invalid object path" error. Thus it's better to use double quotes and escape backslashes in the path.

```
path = "C:\some\folder 'with' quotes"

Function Esc(str)
    Esc = Replace(str, "\", "\\")
End Function

Set wmi = GetObject("winmgmts:") 
Set fs  = wmi.Get("Win32_LogicalFileSecuritySetting=""" & Esc(path) & """")
rc = fs.GetSecurityDescriptor(sd)

If rc = 0 Then
    WScript.Echo "Owner: " & sd.Owner.Domain & "\" & sd.Owner.Name
Else
    WScript.Echo "Couldn't retrieve security descriptor."
End If
```